# PropertiesConfiguration utf-8 encoding

Tags: java

I need to add or change value in property file and save this file layout(coments, order etc). If i use java.util.Properties all comments will be deleted and its changed order. Looks like PropertiesConfiguration from Apache Commons can help me with that but i have problem in saving.

In property file i have this lines(as example):

```
#Comments
Test = Тест
```

When properties file saved this line converted in:

```
Test = \u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442
```

Given code example:

```
public void writeProperty(String key, String value)
{
    try
    {
        config = new PropertiesConfiguration(sFileName);
        config.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        config.setProperty(key, value);
        config.save();
    }
    catch (ConfigurationException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is supposed to be that way. Property files are defined to be in ISO-8859-1 encoding and that Unicode characters have to be escaped accordingly.

Changing that would break the API definition, resulting in a non-standard property file.

See [the according article on wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) for details.

Answer (score 0):

**Since Java 9** the default for `.properties` of PropertyResourceBundles is **UTF-8** as stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm) so you might have a good reasons to write properties with the UTF-8 symbols.

For the `org.apache.commons.configuration2`, you can achieve this by overriding the default `ValueTransformer` used for escaping characters

Kotlin code:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration.DefaultIOFactory
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration.PropertiesWriter
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.convert.ListDelimiterHandler
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.convert.ValueTransformer
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.AggregateTranslator
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.EntityArrays
import org.apache.commons.text.translate.LookupTranslator
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.StringWriter
import java.io.Writer

/**
 * This class is custom implementation of the [ValueTransformer] that prevents escaping of UTF-8 characters
 * UTF-8 is supported in properties files by Java 9
 */
private class Utf8ValueTransformer : ValueTransformer {
  companion object {
    private val charsEscape = mapOf<CharSequence, CharSequence>("\\" to "\\\\")
    private val escapeProperties = AggregateTranslator(
      LookupTranslator(charsEscape), LookupTranslator(
        EntityArrays.JAVA_CTRL_CHARS_ESCAPE
      )
    )
  }

  override fun transformValue(p0: Any?): Any {
    val strVal = p0.toString()
    return escapeProperties.translate(strVal)
  }
}
```

Then you have to extend the DefaultIOFactory:

```
private class Utf8IoFactory : DefaultIOFactory() {
  companion object {
    private val valueTransformer = Utf8ValueTransformer()
  }

  override fun createPropertiesWriter(out: Writer?, handler: ListDelimiterHandler?): PropertiesWriter {
    return PropertiesWriter(out, handler, valueTransformer)
  }
}
```

And finally you can get the result with UTF-8 characters:

```
  private fun PropertiesConfiguration.asByteArray(): ByteArray {
    val writer = StringWriter()
    this.ioFactory = Utf8IoFactory()
    this.write(writer)
    return writer.toString().toByteArray()
  }
```